# Using SVN from existent directory

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, svn, mod-dav-svn

I'm following this [guide](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-svn-subversion-server-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) to install and configure a SVN Server in my development server. I've some previously projects created under /var/www/html and want those projects under SVN meaning I can use Tortoise or any other client to have this code with SCM. Which are the commands to start a new repo at /var/www/html/project1 for example? This one: **svnadmin create testrepo**? How I must configure Apache DAV SVN to allow HTTP access after get the repo configured and working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which are the commands to start a new repo at `/var/www/html/project1`
>   for example? This one: **svnadmin create testrepo**?

```
# cd /var/www/html
# svnadmin create testrepo
```

> I've some previously projects created under `/var/www/html` and want
>   those projects under SVN

```
# cd /var/www/html
# svn import ./foo -m "importing the foo project" file:///var/www/html/testrepo
```

> How I must configure Apache DAV SVN to allow HTTP access after get the
>   repo configured and working?

```
<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /var/www/html/testrepo
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion repositories"
   AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Thx for your reply but still getting doubts. First I've a PHP project located at `/var/www/html/project1` then I initialize the SVN repo at `/var/www/html/svn` running the command `cd /var/www/htmlsvn && svnadmin create cmvrepo` which are the next steps? `svn import ./foo - m "importing the foo project" file:///var/www/html/project1`? (I assume this is any name which are the right word to write there)

Comment: `svn import /var/www/html/project1 file:///var/www/html/svn/cmvrepo -m "importing the project1"`.

Comment: Thx it's working perfectly!!